# Error while using groupby and sum function

Tags: r

I have dataframe as shown below. I am trying to groupby using GO_terms and sum the correspoding values.

```html
GO_terms    Data
ribosome    2.07
integral_component_of_membrane  1.88
integral_component_of_membrane  1.21
membrane    1.21
membrane    1.46
membrane    1.02
membrane    2.5
membrane    1.11
extracellular region    2.31
cytoplasm   1.05
cytoplasm   1.68
cytoplasm   1.03
endoplasmic reticulum membrane  2.47
endoplasmic reticulum membrane  1.6
cytoskeleton    1.86
signal recognition particle 1.11
transcription elongation factor complex 1.62
aminoacyl-tRNA synthetase multienzyme complex   1.18
signal recognition particle receptor complex    1.01
```

I tried using the following code:

```
df %>% group_by(GO_terms) %>% summarise(Frequency = sum(Data))
```

I get the following error:

Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `Frequency`.
ℹ `Frequency = sum(Data)`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: GO_terms = "aminoacyl-tRNA synthetase multienzyme complex".

Could anyone help to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `class(df$Data)` ? Try using `df %>% group_by(GO_terms) %>% summarise(Frequency = sum(as.numeric(Data)))`. It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems that `Data` column is of type character, convert it to numeric before taking the `sum`. Try -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% group_by(GO_terms) %>% summarise(Frequency = sum(as.numeric(Data)))
df
```